# How to play the same note on piano?

Tags: piano

[image]Please explain how to play the same note A with both hands in this measure.

Comment: I find the fact that the damper pedal is used here leads to a different answer from the possible duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

Since it's pedalled all through the bar, play the r.h. lower A, pedal, and then play the l.h. A each time it comes. No need to hold the r.h. A key down - the pedalling will sustain it.