# How would I play this Bach's piece (bar) on piano - from Polonaise in G major

Tags: theory, piano, technique

As you see in this picture, we have a black note on B and a quarter note on B also.
[image]

So my question is when my finger is on note B (for black note) how second B could play? I don't see a connecting legato also? If it means something else please tell me.

Comment: You play the B a second time. http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4670/the-same-note-on-two-staves?noredirect=1&lq=1
http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/how-to-play-the-same-note-on-piano

Comment: I feel obligated to note that Bach did not write for piano.  Pianos did not come in use commonly until after his death, and even then they were not like modern pianos.  That is not to say you shouldn't play it (you should!), but that it is more properly termed a "keyboard" piece.

Comment: This kind of notation is very common in keyboard music, because conventional notation was meant to be interpreted by *humans* using their musical experience and common sense. A "mathematically exact" notation would look more complicated, but doesn't really convey any more information. Of course *computer* playback may not interpret the "human" notation correctly, but that's a different problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the instrument you play, its sustain, and on the speed and loudness you play the piece at.

Basically, you want the attack of the second B without a release of the first B.  If the sustain of the instrument is strong enough and the second voice is loud enough, just smoothly releasing the G "legato" and then moving on to the C next beat may work fine, particularly on instruments or volumes with a comparatively soft attack.

Otherwise you release the B not far enough for the tone to dampen and let it strike again with a volume appropriate for the first voice.

The latter option will work particularly well on grand pianos (which tend to have a repeat mechanic that supports this kind of option) but is also feasible for pianos.

On a harpsichord, you'll also want to repeat since the attack has a very characteristic sound and its absence would be quite noticeable.  On a harmonium/organ/accordion, not interrupting the B at all might be preferable.

Try it out and see which execution better allows your hearing to focus on either line without too much irritation.

Comment: " On a harmonium/organ/accordion, not interrupting the B at all might be preferable." I disagree with that. If the composer didn't *want* you to repeat the note, why did he waste his time writing it? You might need to make a longer space *before* the note on an instrument with a relatively slow attack time, like an accordion.